# How do I initialize a constant from a function?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing a module which will use [Sequel ORM](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel). I want to be able to set the `DB` constant so it's available in the global namespace but I can't figure out a non-hacky way to do so. Here's what I have so far:

```
require 'sequel'

module BB

  class Dal    

    def initialize(db_url)
      self.class.connect(db_url)
    end

    def self.connect(db_url)
      @db = Sequel.connect( db_url )
    end
  end  

  BB::Dal.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL']) if ENV['DATABASE_URL']
end
```

As you can see I'd like to enable two modes of initialization. Either through the `ENV['DATABASE_URL']` variable or through a constructor. What I'd like to do now is replace `@db` with `DB`. Any ideas?

Comment: If initialized from code, it's not really a constant, is it? A singleton or class method seems much more appropriate here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just kick that out of the `module` context if you want:

```
DB = BB::Dal.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL']) if ENV['DATABASE_URL']
```

It's worth noting that jamming these things in the root namespace is probably bad form. You might want to have a database connection module to organize these:

```
module DB
  def connection
    # Lazy initializer pattern applied here
    @connection ||= BB::Dal.connect(ENV['DATABASE_URL'])
  end
end

# ...

# Will connect the first time it's called, recycle the connection
# for all subsequent calls.
DB.connection.do_stuff
```

It really depends on how this will be used. The advantage of a method is it's very easy to upgrade to a connection pool should the occasion arise, whereas a constant is very rigid in terms of function, it must return a singular value with no opportunity to run code first.

Comment: Having the `DB` constant is recommended in Sequel's docs. The problem is that if I initialize `DB` directly from the `ENV` var I won't be able to give the option to pass a connection string in case the user wants to use something other than the `ENV` variable.

Comment: Sequel's documentation does recommend something that works in a very general sense, but it breaks down pretty quickly if you want to do anything even remotely beyond that. An initializer like the one I've suggested here is a lot more flexible and allows you to set up whatever you need to, such as reading a config file, checking environment  variables, or whatever, before committing to a connection call. You could implement all of this in your existing module so you can do `BB::Dal.db` instead of calling `connect` at all.